# Is there a rule of thumb for zero padding in image processing?

Tags: fft, image-processing, zero-padding

I see there are a lot of answers on why zero padding is necessary and how it avoids wrapping around the sides of images. However is there a rule of thumb on how much padding will be good for the image processing? I am mainly thinking from the point of view of:

a.) speed of processing the image

b.) noise

I have till now referred to the following answers:

1. [Why images need to be padded before filtering in frequency domain](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3444/why-images-need-to-be-padded-before-filtering-in-frequency-domain/28978)
2. [Advantages/disadvantage of zero padding](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/22034/advantages-disadvantage-of-zero-padding)
3. [FFT Zero Padding - Amplitude Change](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8167/fft-zero-padding-amplitude-change/8625#8625)

Response will be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: you said "zero-padding against wrapping around the sides of the image"; what is the *operation* you do that leads to that wrapping?

Comment: @MarcusMüllerI didn't get your question. Sorry. Could you please help e understand if your question was specific to my code a question in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Press et al. "Numerical Recipes in C++". Chapter 13 on "Fourier and Spectral Applications", Section 13.1 with a subsection entitled "Treatment of end effects by zero padding".  This is perhaps the best summary of zero-padding anywhere in the literature (but it's not referenced in either the contents or index).  My edition of this book is the 2002 second edition and the page number there is 545.

Comment: This is a gem of a book Jones. Thank you. I am reading the recommended chapter for the answer. Thank you. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I do consider zero-padding as a form of an often-used combination of two other basic operations:

- "extension",
- "windowing",

for finite-length data (signals, images).

[Interlude] I don't know a generic word for that (like [*companding*, that combines compressing and expanding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companding)). Fellow SE.DSPers, if you know of one, please share. Otherwise, I would propose "**extowing**". I will start with the "windowing" part.

- **Windowing:**
  While there is a huge literature in the design of 1D windows, I have neither  been teached/exposed, nor seen so much references, on 2D (and nD) designs. If I focus on 2D windows *per se* (not for other purposes than windowing),  in my bibliographic reference list (10.900+ items  and counting), there is only a handful of such references, mostly ancient, like: [Huang, T. S., 1970, Two-dimensional windows](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/717159.pdf) (quote: "Many good one-dimensional windows have been devised, however, relatively
  few two-dimensional windows have been investigated.") or [Coulombe, S. and Dubois, E., 1996, Multidimensional windows over arbitrary lattices and their application to FIR filter design](https://dx.doi.org/10.1109/ICASSP.1996.547762). Most *per se*  designs I know of are:

  - [tensor, separable outer-products of 1D windows](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/41688/15892),
  - non-separable circular extensions of 1D designs, where a centered $W(t)=w(|t-t_0|)$ window is converted to 2D with some norm $l$: $W(x)=w(l(x-x_0))$, with discretization and normalization side-effects,
  - non-separable "1D-inspired" 2D optimization (like McClellan).

However, I have not seen a lot  of them natively implemented in image processing software (apart from tensorized 1D windows and [2D discretized Gaussians](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/gsmooth.htm)).

- **Extension:** data extension is common practice in image processing, for different reasons. For instance, in [JPEG Discrete cosine transform padding](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/35343/15892), one uses extensions to process images whose width or height are not divisible by 8. Additionally, DCT type II has beneficial symmetric features that are practically useful. 
  A mere zero-padding can be applied, but the risk of strong artifacts at the borders is very high. Useful extensions can be strongly dependent on image applications and morphology. For instance, many sound/vibration signals are zero-mean, and can easily be zero-extended with a little tapering. Meanwhile, standard images have $[0,255]$ pixel values, and hence are not zero-mean. So constant (zero-order) or linear extensions are sometimes used at borders, and there exists a literature on windowing for adaptive (causal) image filtering ([R.M. Mersereau ; D.E. Dudgeon, 1975, Two-dimensional digital filtering](https://doi.org/10.1109/PROC.1975.9795)
  or [J.H. McClellan, 1982, Multidimensional spectral estimation](https://doi.org/10.1109/PROC.1982.12431)).

Both operations (Windowing and Extensions) are naturally combined in the design of multirate or multiscale filter banks, where parallel  banks of windowed pass-band filters are designed together to allow both overlap between pixel blocks (to avoid sharp discontinuities) and perfect reconstruction (exact inversion). The Lapped Orthogonal Transform (LOT) is typical, with 50% overlap on each side. Embedded in the context of [paraunitary filter filter banks](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/sasp/Paraunitary_Filter_Banks.html), many works have derived symmetric or antisymmetric image extensions, to benefit from the inherent symmetries in the filters. The typology is often four-fold, with [half-sample or whole sample symmetry, and symmetry or antisymmetry](https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/signal-extension-modes.html). They are sought to preserve "image" continuity or differentiability across blocks.

But let's get practical. If you have enough memory, my experience is that you are really safe, in the first instance,  if you perform a 4-fold image extension (symmetric or antisymmetric depending on the data) and windowing: 50% on each edge, and a separable 1D window design, with a power-raised cosine window.

Comment: Hi Laurent, Thaks for the detailed reply. If I understand it correctly, you tell a lot about how image continuity can be preserved and (padding) is useful for image reconstruction. However, I still did not get how it helps in speed and noise. Sorry but some rephrasing would be really helpful!

Comment: I am not sure I understand your concerns on speed and noise. For speed, padding can help when it casts the image to a manageable size (like 8x8 blocks in JPEG). For noise, windowing can reduce symmetric wrapping artifacts. Are you digging into those directions?

Comment: Umm, somewhat. For example, if I add padding (take any padding -zero or non-zero) to an image, will increasing/decreasing padding help? I can think like if we increase padding a lot that there may be too much background and hence noise but too less, will give sharper edges during processing. Definitely, we can use windowing to filter out some frequencies, but is there a rule of thumb as to how much padding would be good?

Similarly, padding is basically adding more pixels in the image to be processed. How will padding affect the speed during any image processing?

Comment: I am not sure I got all your comments. Padding can increase or decrease speed, ease or more more difficult processing depending on the image content and symmetries